# Special GUI-related Parallel patterns. Do they exist?

Tags: .net, user-interface, asynchronous

Async programming becomes more natural.
C# now supports async/await.
And all this allows us write resposnive applications as Anders Hejlsberg said [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-816T).
Our team likes asynchrony too. But we had to develop some helper methods for convenience as we code for .net v.4.0

But the more we use async operations the more difficult it becomes.
Just an example:

We have a master-detail part of GUI. When user clicks some master item quite long operation starts to get the details. This operation can be inherently unstoppable like db request or file downloading. So we start this long operation asynchronously for UI to stay responsive.
Now we have to decide what to do with the master items list.
We can allow user to change the item and start new operation. The results of already running operation can be abandoned now or put to cache.
And let's imagine now that user clicks item1, item2 and then item1 again. When he does this rather quick the already started and not cancelled operation for item1 can be still not completed. In this case we better to wait for the result of this operation rather than start a new one. Hence, some cache of currently executing operations must exist. (have no idea how this can be easily done with await)
Sure we can disable master-items list till the very completion of the operation but is not very user frineldy though other parts of UI stay live.

*The second example (the upgrade to the first one):*
the details part of GUI consists of two lists. Each list's content depends on the selected master item. In addition to that lists affect each other in a way that selection in one list changes the state of the other. (yes, quite complex use case).
Now what if we want the data for both lists be acquired asynchronously?
We do not know in advance which list wins the race and gets its data first. This really does not matter. What matters is the very fact of the winner existence. List One completed, user changes a selection...but wait this selection should affect the state of not yet populated list Two. Again we can prohibit selections before both lists loaded but there are many independent operations user can do with the lists. Thus, this is not a choice.
Ok, how can we do with this? Well, we could introduce the task to be started when both lists loaded. In this task we can get current selections and set states as we need.

And what is the point?
I've read about parallel programming in [general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx) but I believe GUI to be a very secial case because user interactions make GUI change it state randomly (from the point of view of the execution flow). As we have gui related design patterns (MVC, MVP, MVVM) we must have special parallel patterns

Here is my question:

**Do dedicated parallel paterns exist which addres common async-GUI tasks?**

P.S. If you believe this question better fits programmers.stackexchange, please, fell free to migrate it. Thank you.

Comment: I do this with BackgroundWorker and supports cancellation.  It is just a lot of detail.  If you don't cancel the work what can happen is a lot of work gets thrown away and you eat up resources.  WPF UI is a different beast as only the main thread can update the UI and therefore in WPF there is not parallel UI pattern.  And once the UI starts to render there is no cancel so use virtualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that it's not uncommon to rethink the UI when converting a desktop program to be asynchronous. An asynchronous program can have many more possible states than the corresponding synchronous program.

There's a couple of useful patterns: disable the controls (or, equivalently, covering them with a "Loading..." sign), and keep a state "context" (which I explain below). You could also maintain a queue of operations, but most people don't bother because building a UI for managing a queue of operations is not easy.

> This operation can be inherently unstoppable like db request or file downloading.

(Side note: neither of these are inherently unstoppable)

> We can allow user to change the item and start new operation. The results of already running operation can be abandoned now or put to cache.

Those are both reasonable approaches, depending on your application and the type of operation.

> And let's imagine now that user clicks item1, item2 and then item1 again. When he does this rather quick the already started and not cancelled operation for item1 can be still not completed. In this case we better to wait for the result of this operation rather than start a new one. Hence, some cache of currently executing operations must exist.

I don't recommend designing for pathological user scenarios. In this case, if the user really is clicking around that master list at an alarming rate, then let them live with the performance degradation. If you're really concerned about it, you can cache the results (as you mentioned above) so that the re-execution of item1 will be extremely fast. The cache of results should be sufficient; you shouldn't need a cache of executing operations.

> Sure we can disable master-items list till the very completion of the operation but is not very user frineldy though other parts of UI stay live.

One thing to keep in mind is that it's no *less* user-unfriendly than the synchronous application, which (presumably) just goes unresponsive during this time.

> Each list's content depends on the selected master item. In addition to that lists affect each other in a way that selection in one list changes the state of the other.

You may want to re-think your UI. Do you really need one this complex? Think of it another way: is there *any* publicly-available application that you use that has a UI this complex? What do they do instead?

That said, there is an old asynchronous programming trick that I explain on my blog: [asynchronous callback contexts](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/asynchronous-callback-contexts.html). Essentially, the idea is that you use a "cookie" to define the "current" state (for some scope); when the state changes, you change the "cookie". All asynchronous methods that are a part of that scope can monitor the cookie and take special action when it changes.

You can use `object` for a cookie (as I describe on my blog), but you can also use `CancellationToken`:

```
private CancellationTokenSource masterListSelectionCookie;
private Task list1Download;
private Task list2Download;

void MasterList_Click(...)
{
  // Change the cookie, canceling any previous one.
  if (masterListSelectionCookie != null)
    masterListSelectionCookie.Cancel();
  masterListSelectionCookie = new CancellationTokenSource();

  // Clear out both lists.
  list1.Items.Clear();
  list2.Items.Clear();

  // Start both lists downloading.
  list1Download = DownloadList1Async();
  list2Download = DownloadList2Async();
}

async void List1_Click(...)
{
  // Get a local copy of the current cookie.
  var localMasterListSelectionCookie = masterListSelectionCookie.Token;

  // Ensure list2 is done downloading.
  await list2Download;

  // If the cookie has changed, ignore the click.
  if (localMasterListSelectionCookie.IsCancellationRequested)
    return;

  // Apply the click changes to list2 items.
  FilterList2(list1.Item);
}

async void List2_Click(...)
{
  // Get a local copy of the current cookie.
  var localMasterListSelectionCookie = masterListSelectionCookie.Token;

  // Ensure list1 is done downloading.
  await list1Download;

  // If the cookie has changed, ignore the click.
  if (localMasterListSelectionCookie.IsCancellationRequested)
    return;

  // Apply the click changes to list1 items.
  FilterList1(list2.Item);
}
```

The idea is that for each operation that is sensitive to the "state" implicit in the cookie, they check after each `await` to see if the cookie has changed (i.e., the `CancellationToken` has been cancelled) and take appropriate behavior (in this case, just not filtering the other list).

Comment: Yes, we do the same with the state checking the cancelattion token source. That is exactly what we added some methods for as I wrote above. Thank you for explanation. I liked "pathalogic user scenario" =) It's indeen reasonable no to support this behavior.